# Creando un archivo csv en mysql con fecha actual

Tags: mysql

¿Cómo se pueden exportar datos de `mysql` a un archivo`cvs` con la fecha y hora del día? Intento este código pero me sale un error. Estoy intentado hacer un `evento`

Mi Evento

```
CREATE DEFINER = `admin`@`localhost` EVENT `Respaldo Ordenes` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY1 MONTH STARTS '2018-12-01 00:00:00' 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
COMMENT 'Respaldo de Ordenes cada fin de mes' 
DO SELECT *
FROM Order
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/_orders.csv'
```

Pero quiero agregarle la fecha para que no se duplique con el mismo nombre

```
SELECT *
FROM order
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/',NOW(),'_orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

error

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"' ,NOW(), '"'_orders.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TER' at line 3
```

Investigando encontre este codigo

```
SET @`outfull` := CONCAT('/tmp/', NOW(), 'orders.csv');
SET @`qry` := CONCAT('SELECT * 
                        INTO OUTFILE \'', @`outfull`, '\' 
                        FIELDS TERMINATED BY \';\' 
                        ENCLOSED BY \'"\' 
                        LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\' 
                      FROM `order`');

PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`qry`;
SET @`qry` := NULL;
EXECUTE `stmt`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
```

Pero si lo agrego al evento me tira este error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo ejecutando SQL dinámico dentro del evento, de esta manera:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER = `admin`@`localhost` EVENT `Respaldo Ordenes`
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 MONTH
STARTS '2018-12-01 00:00:00' 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
COMMENT 'Respaldo de Ordenes cada fin de mes' 
DO
BEGIN
    SET @sql_stmt := concat("SELECT * FROM Order INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/", DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d %H%i%s'), "_orders.csv'");
        PREPARE extrct FROM @sql_stmt;
        EXECUTE extrct;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE extrct;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: me sacaste de un gran apuro! Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograrlo usando `BEGIN` y `END` de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE EVENT `Respaldo Ordenes` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH 
STARTS '2018-12-01 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
COMMENT 'Respaldo de Ordenes cada fin de mes' 
DO BEGIN

    SET @stmt := CONCAT("SELECT * FROM Order INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/", NOW(), "_orders.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");
    PREPARE qry FROM @sql_stmt;
    EXECUTE qry;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE qry;

END
```